# How to increase the width of ASP.NET MVC Select tag helper inside form

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

The width of the `Select tag helper` in the following veiw remains fixed no matter what value I change in its style attribute `style="width:10000px;"`. Whether it's set to 10px or 10000px the width remains the same. On the other hand, in the same example below, the input tag ProjectNumber along with the Instructions message (correctly) occupies the entire width of the computer screen. **Note** 1: It's a multi select dropdown (but I think that should not mater). 2. I'm using `VS2015-Update3` that comes with built-in `Bootstrap` functionality:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("MainLeftMenu")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <form id="target" asp-controller="myTest" asp-action="myAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SelectedIDs" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="SelectedIDs" asp-items="Model.myList" style="width:10000px;"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input asp-for="ProjectNumber" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">Instructions: Add number in the format such as: ABC-123-xyz-000</div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Test</button>
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use your browser's Web Inspector (F12) tools to examine the `<select>`. Also as this is a client-side issue please post the **rendered HTML**, not the cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap for the select in form you can add class="form-control" like input type text.

For reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: But how do you increase the width of Select tag. It's not changing the width when I try it.

Comment: With class form-control css add width 100%

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding `style="min-width:700px;overflow:auto;"` to the `select tag helper`. You can change `700px` to whatever width you need.